# Achieve screen sharing through browser

Tags: browser, webrtc

How to achieve screen sharing using web browsers ? Can any one helps me to give a best solution for achieving the screen sharing.

Comment: Try [getScreenId.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/getScreenId.js) on chrome (HTTPs) or Firefox Nightly (both HTTP and HTTPs).... for Firefox you need to enable some flags. For chrome you can install either chrome extension or enable a command-line flag. Remember, HTTPs is mandatory for chrome however using another command-line flag, you can support HTTP as well. In the same repository, you can find [screen.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/screen-sharing) and many other chrome-extension based screen sharing demos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getUserMedia` and set the option so that it captures screen

```
video: {
   mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
      maxWidth: 1280,
      maxHeight: 720
   },
   optional: []
}
```

A good example:
http://bloggeek.me/implement-screen-sharing-webrtc/

And don't forget to enable the screen capture in Chrome. Also I'm not that sure about the support on other browsers than chrome.

The screen can then be transfered to another user using `RTCPeerConnection`